# Combinatorics problem - bingo - cartons

Tags: combinatorics

what is the largest collection of k-element subsets of an n-element set such that each pair of subsets has as maximum m elements in common?

Example:

I have a universe of 90 numbers.

I need to form cartons (sets) that have 10 numbers in total, but at most 5 numbers are repeated in each carton.

There can not be 2 cartons that have 6 numbers in common.

Comment: Please edit this to show your work! I learned my lesson the hard way about that, and many people will appreciate helping you to assist your thought process.

Comment: @PhilTheLawyer at very least it shows where the person got stuck.